# Calculating time difference between 2 dates in Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm trying to calculate time difference (in months) between the current date, and the date the customer opened his account (only for those who joined in January 2012).
I try to use `current_date` and `cast`, but I think my problem is in my date field which is in the following format: *dd/mm/yyyy*
I'm working on Teradata.
Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: can you show us the query you actually did? the code itself, that'd be helpful for us to help you

Comment: My code is: **SELECT CURRENT_DATE-CAST(startDate) FROM myTable WHERE startDate BETWEEN 1120101 AND 1120131

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
SELECT CURRENT_DATE - CAST('2016-06-06' AS DATE) MONTH(4);
```

and if your date is in dd/mm/yyyy format then you can try like

```
SELECT CURRENT_DATE - cast(myDate as date format 'YYYY-MM-DD') MONTH(4);
```

Comment: What is the significance of adding month(4) at the end? Can you share some reference?